# Encyption with blowfish without plus sign

Tags: php, openssl, urlencode

I want to pass an encrypted string as url parameter, below is my php script

```
$passphrase = "testte@t";
$cipher = "blowfish";
$id = "20220228-12";
$enc_str = openssl_encrypt($id, $cipher, $passphrase);
$url = "https://example.com/?p={$enc_str}";
```

finally the $url is encrypted as

```
https://example.com/?p=BNrdu+t/YVgefLcrCxmuug==
```

if I get the value of parameter using $_REQUEST['p'], the encryped string will be returned as **BNrdu t/YVgefLcrCxmuug==** which lost the char sign '+', how can I avoid the encrypted string with the char '+'? Should I change another cipher? Which one is the best?

Comment: You have to use `urlencode` when building the url and `urldecode` when parsing the value.

Comment: I did try to urlencode the url but when access the site with this encoded url, browser still decode the url and parameter contain char sign '+'

Answer (score 0):

```php
$param = "BNrdu+t/YVgefLcrCxmuug==";

$encoded = urlencode($param);


echo "https://example.com/?p=$encoded";
```

will output `https://example.com/?p=BNrdu%2Bt%2FYVgefLcrCxmuug%3D%3D`.

Then when receiving data:

```php
$param = urldecode($_GET["p"] ?? ""); // BNrdu+t/YVgefLcrCxmuug==
```